# Switch Applications Within One Space

Tags: macos, mac, workspace

Is there a way to set a key binding so that it would cycle application with a single workspace?

Command+tab would go through all the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default way hidden in

`System Preferences->Keyboard->Keyboard Shortcuts->Keyboard & Text Input->Move focus to next active or next window`

It doesn't show a list of the windows tho, it just switches to the next window. It also sometimes seemed to switch to an application that had no windows so I installed Witch.

http://manytricks.com/witch/

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this by default in OS X but [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/), an application I developed, does this by default - the windows are grouped by Space and window activity.

Comment: Wow, your app is lovely -- I hodge-podged some Applescript to do the basics, but your UI is so elegant!!!